# $E_C$-$E_F$ in the equation for concentration of electrons at equilibrium

Tags: semiconductor-physics, equilibrium, fermi-energy

I'm trying to calculate the charge carrier concentration for silicon doped with phosphorous at a level of $10^{16}$ per cubic centimeter.

I have the formula: $$n_0=n_ie^{-(E_C-E_F)/kT}$$

I found $n_i$ to be $1.5 \times 10^{10}$, and $kT$ is 0.026eV at room temperature, but I don't know how to find $E_C$ or $E_F$

Thanks!

Edit 1: I should add that I know conceptually that $E_C-E_f$ is the difference in energy between the conduction band and the Fermi level, but I don't know how to find the actual values

Comment: In your book there likely is a table listing the dopant levels relative to the conduction or valence band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you show is for the intrinsic charge carrier concentration, i.e., that of an undoped semiconductor. If you dope silicon with phosphorous you can drastically change the charge carrier concentration as the phosphorous atoms become ionized at room temperature. You can assume that the extrinsic charge carrier concentration, i.e., that coming from the dopant atoms is the same as the concentration of the dopant atoms.

That being said, the bandgap of silicon is well known. On wikipedia [it is given as 1.11 eV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap#List_of_band_gaps). For the intrinsic case you can assume that $E_F$ is in the center of the gap.